# Dynamically Adding BalancerMembers to Proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-proxy

Running Apache 2.4 I would like to be able to dynamically add  BalanaceMembers via API to a balancer group in the proxy_balancer module.

There are hints that this is possible. The documentation for [mod_proxy_express](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_express.html) says mod_proxy_balancer "provides dynamic growth."

I see that there is a [BalancerGrowth](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#balancergrowth) directive, which I have tried adding but see no more slots in the balancer-manager page.

How do I provide for dynamic growth of proxy balancer members? How do I add and remove them? Where is the documentation for the API for adding, removing, and managing members?

Answer (score 0):

this does not yet work for me because i do not see something in the user-interface how i would add it but maybe this helps you. i will give you an update if i find out something new

i used the configuration option mentioned in [this thread](http://apache-http-server.18135.x6.nabble.com/mod-proxy-balancer-balancer-manager-questions-td5000155.html)

```
<Proxy balancer://myset growth=5>
    BalancerMember http://localhost:8080 route=8080
    BalancerMember http://localhost:8081 route=8081
    ProxySet lbmethod=bybusyness
    ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONID 
</Proxy>
```

---

EDIT

if you click on the lb-link there is a new input field and a checkbox. here you can add new workers. i don't know if one can remove them though. maybe just disabling hosts is possible